# Representations of Lie Groups in Arbitrary Co-ordinates

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Seeing that a Lie group is a manifold, one should be able to work in arbitrary co-ordinates on that manifold. However I have not seen any discussion of how representations of a Lie group and it's algebra are affected by such co-ordinate transformations.

For example, consider the 1-dimensional translation group, with representations of group element $x$ denoted by $U[x]$. An example of such a representation is:
\begin{equation}
U[x]\vert p\rangle=e^{-ipx}\vert p\rangle
\end{equation}
Now I should be able to change co-ordinates on the group manifold by:
\begin{equation}
\xi=\tanh(x)
\end{equation}
So that the action of group element $\xi$ (which is just group element $x$ in another co-ordinate system) is:
\begin{equation}
U[\xi]\vert p\rangle=e^{-i p\tanh^{-1}(\xi)}\vert p\rangle
\end{equation}
And this still forms a representation because one can quickly check that:
$U[\xi_a]U[\xi_b]=U[\xi_a\cdot \xi_b]$.

*Questions: (1) Is it true that one can work in any co-ordinates on the group manifold for a representation of a Lie group and it's Lie algebra?
(2) If one does so, then group elements are typically no longer the exponential of Lie algebra elements?
(3) Has anything useful ever been learnt by working in non-exponential co-ordinates? (4) Is the following statement is correct: there is a preferred class of co-ordinates (canonical co-ordinates) on a Lie group because the action of a group element on the manifold generates a diffeomorphism so one might as well use the orbits generated by such a diffeomorphism as co-ordinates?*

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can work in arbitrary coordinates, but often you don't need to work in coordinates at all.
2. Group elements near the identity are always the exponential of elements of the Lie algebra; this is a coordinate-invariant fact.
3. I don't know. Again, often you don't need to work in coordinates at all. Off the top of my head I'm not aware of any results in Lie theory proven using any coordinates other than possibly the local coordinates given by the exponential map or possibly the local coordinates given by the exponential map with respect to a bi-invariant Riemannian metric.
4. I don't know what you mean by this.